# Can't grant permission on class scoped to belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have `CourseClass` model which has many `AttendanceSheet`s and `has_many` `Teacher`s. I want the teacher(s) of a course_class instance to be able to manage that course_class's attendance sheets.

I'd expect the following to set that up:

```
if user.has_role? :teacher
  can [:manage], AttendanceSheet, course_class: { teachers: {id: user.id } }
end
```

Users have a global roles, but also can have per-instance roles on a CourseClass. The above, in theory, should check they have the global role, and then the `teachers` association finds only teachers with an instance role on that CourseClass.

In the controller @attendance_sheets is set by:

`@attendance_sheets = @course_class.attendance_sheets.all`

When I run ability checks I get the following results:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb011970ea0>>)> can? :read, @attendance_sheets
=> false
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb011970ea0>>)> can? :read, AttendanceSheet
=> true
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb011970ea0>>)> can? :read, @course_class.attendance_sheets
=> false
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb011970ea0>>)> can? :manage, AttendanceSheet
=> true
```

I expected/want `read`/`manage` on `AttendanceSheet` to be `false` and `:read` on `@attendance_sheets` or `@course_class.attendance_sheets` to be `true`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You always should test permissions by specific model examples, not whole class. I don't think there is a way to do this as want.

If you want to add permissions to specific set of instances, you automatically have permissions to the class. You should get those set without granted access and then check permissions to those instances.